# Altering face colors in the python API

Tags: python, color

There must be something that I am fundamentally missing. I am using the python API to generate a mesh and object. I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to change the face color of the object I just made. I don't get any errors in the code, but the color just doesn't seem to update.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

meshes = bpy.data.meshes
objects = bpy.data.objects

if 'topo_mesh' in meshes:
    meshes.remove(meshes['topo_mesh'])
mesh = meshes.new('topo_mesh')

if 'topo_obj' in objects:
    objects.remove(objects['topo_obj'])
obj = objects.new('topo_obj',mesh)

vertices = [(-1,-1,0),(1,-1,0),(1,1,0),(-1,1,0)]
faces = [(0,1,2,3)]

mesh.from_pydata(vertices,[],faces)

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)
color_layer = bm.loops.layers.color.new("color")
for face in bm.faces:
    for loop in face.loops:
        loop[color_layer] = (1,0,0,1)
bm.to_mesh(mesh)  

view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer
view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

Why isn't the object turning red?

[image]

My overall goal is to change a .txt file with topography into an object where each location is colored according to some user-specified color map. I've got the mesh generation down already, I just do not know how to color the faces. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Edited:
Thanks for your help. I'll have to look at your modification to figure out why I couldn't get it working. I'm getting closer. :)

[image: It's working!]

Comment: Are you using a viewport shading mode that supports displaying face colors? Are the face colors being used at all? Are they used in a way that produces visible results?

Comment: Yes, viewport shading is on. I can change the color using the sidebar and view it. I just cannot change it from my python script. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm also able to use Edit Mode manually to individually change the faces of colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just expose your color into material:

[image]

python:

```
# adding material and setup nodes:
mat = bpy.data.materials.new("topo_mat")
mat.use_nodes = True
node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeAttribute")
mat.node_tree.links.new(node.outputs['Color'], mat.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs[0])
node.attribute_name = "color"

# set material to the object:
obj.data.materials.append(mat)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to reproduce using only the python scripting?

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: THANKS! that worked!